# NetApp cluster fail to start

Tags: cluster, storage-area-network, netapp

I have a big problem with my FAS2020 (configured as iScsi storage for 2 esxi 4 server).
I couldn't ping the 2 ip address of the FAS so I connect by the serial port with putty for monitoring the boot flow.
I got a lot of error as shown on attached image.
I try to run "autoboot" command from the loader but it goes in a infinite restart loop.

I'm not expert in cluster configuration but I think it is a very serious problem, could someone help me in this or give me some basic advice?

[image: IMAGE: Boot Errors]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got an internal FC bus error - very likely to be a hardware issue. You'd going to have to get NetApp to fix the broken bit sorry.

If you have no support contract can you let me know where you are in the world please, I have a few spare FAS2020's at my storage location in the UK, if you're nearby you could have one or the part.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Chopper, I'm from Verona (italy), but first of all I'll try to check if I have a support contract yet. So, I cannot make other test?

Comment: No, it's broke sorry.